Maximum length of externalId in Autodesk Platform Service
In the model derivatives of Autodesk Platform Service (Forge), after the translation process we can download properties.json. In that file, we have an attribute called "externalId". So, I want to know the maximum length allowed for that field
After downloading properties.json for different CAD files, I noticed that the values for externalId does not have a unique pattern

The External id from Viewer depends on the input file that generates it.
From Revit perspective, it will always be the unique id, which is a guid as described at https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/get-dbid-externalid.
For AutoCAD, it will be the handle,  as described at Autodesk Forge - DGN file element externalId
Check aditional details here
There is no documented maximum size for the external_id field.
